# Page Height will expand upon refresh only, not initial load (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

When I load the page for the first time and the table I have within it is empty, the page/footer/etc. will come up and sit right beneath it, rather than extend to the bottom of the viewport as I want. However, that does happen when I refresh.

I have form helpers to load content in side the main layout. They're each in a container tag. I tried many different combinations of setting my elements/divs to height:100% but none worked. They still only looked closer to how I want them after refresh. Happens on multiple browsers.
Rails 5
Ruby 2.3.1

In my application.html.erb:

```
    <div class=<%= (defined? @home) ? "home" : "pages" %>>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="page-wrapper" >       
        <%= bootstrap_flash %>        
        <%= yield %>   
    </div> 
    <%= render "footer" %>
```

CSS:

```
    .home #page-wrapper {
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin: 0 0 0 0px!important;
    }
    .footer {
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

Let me know if there's any other info I can give.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like it might be an issue with your js loading. Can you show us the `<head>` in your layout?

Comment: Sure, I attached the entire head in codepen:
https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/bKeNVo
It's quite extensive (we're using a lot of js, google charts, etc, so I thought I'd include the whole thing)